# Is backtrace() - backtrace_symbols() availible for QNX?

Tags: c++, qt, qnx

I am doing a Qt project. Below are the my set up details.
- Qt Version: Qt 5.5.1(qnx)
- Kits Information: static of Qt5.5.1 of QNX of 6.6.0 armv7
- Compiler: QCC for QNX 6.6.0 armv7
- Qt Mkspec: qnx-armle-v7-qcc

What I want to do is in my project to capture SIGSEGV signal at run time and print the back traces at console itself. I could get back-traces easily in Linux using backtrace()/ backtrace_symbols(). But as "execinfo.h" file is not present in QNX, I can not use backtrace()/ backtrace_symbols() functions.

So, I am thinking to download "execinfo.h" file and add it to my project. And I am sure I will be needing corresponding library as well but there is no idea about library name as of now.

Can someone comment on following?
1. Which is the corresponding library to "execinfo.h" file? 
2. What all I need to get/download for making backtrace()/ backtrace_symbols() functional in QNX?
3. Is there any alternative to print back-traces & symbols at console itself
in Qt/Qnx project?

Comment: `#include <backtrace.h>` and link in libbacktrace. Don't expect it to work in all cases and don't expect any support from QNX.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can try libBacktrace.so, more specifically the bt_get_backtrace() API. Here are the docs for QNX 6.6.0:

http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.6.0_anm11_wf10/#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref/topic/b/bt_get_backtrace.html

There is a warning about the API being fragile and unsupported so proceed at your own risk.